# Run imported function via another function

Tags: javascript, function, import

**Starting point:** With this code I trigger func2 via func1. This works fine so far.

```
window.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  func1("func2()")
})

function func1(functionAsString) {
  eval(functionAsString)
}

function func2() {
  alert("success!")
}
```

**The problem:**
As soon as I import func2 from another javascript file. I can't run func2 with this code anymore....
I have tried it with both import variants

`import * as myfunc from "./xy" // myfunc[functionAsString]`

as well as

`import {func2} from "./xy" // eval(functionAsString)`

and unfortunately I do not get func2 addressed.

**Can someone give me the decisive tip?** Gladly without `.eval()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated your problem in a local environment and it works fine

I also did that on codesanbox and it didn't work here

The problem is that in the codesandbox environment `parcel` was used which transpiles the files and changes the names of the functions hence it couldn't find the name

Anyway, this should work fine in either case:

```
import * as myfunc from "./xy"
myfunc['func2']()
```